# Texture mapping problems and How to cahnge the texture mapping location in WebGL

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am trying to map a texture at a cube, but I came across two problems and one question

here is the code for initialize the cube

```
function init_cube(gl, n)
  {
      const vertices = new Float32Array([   // Vertex coordinates
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  
        // v0-v1-v2-v3 front, Pass
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  
        // v0-v3-v4-v5 right, No
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  
        // v0-v5-v6-v1 up, Pass
       -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  
       // v1-v6-v7-v2 left, Pass
       -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  
       // v7-v4-v3-v2 down, No
        1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0
      // v4-v7-v6-v5 back, Pass
     ]);

    const indices = new Uint8Array([       // Indices of the vertices
      0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3,    // front
      4, 5, 6,   4, 6, 7,    // right
      8, 9,10,   8,10,11,    // up
     12,13,14,  12,14,15,    // left
     16,17,18,  16,18,19,    // down
     20,21,22,  20,22,23     // back
   ]);


    const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
    const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    if(!indexBuffer)
    {
      console.log("Failed to create an index buffer");
      return;
    }

    if(!initArrayBuffer(gl, vertices, 3, gl.FLOAT, loc_aPosition))
    {
      console.log("Failed to initialize an array buffer for the position");
      return;
    }


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    init_texture(gl);

    gl.bindVertexArray(null);

    return {vao, n:indices.length};
}
```

and the code for the texture, I referenced this [tutorial](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) while I making this code

```
function init_texture(gl)
{  
    const UVCoord = new Float32Array
    (
      [
        //First Pass
        0, 0.75,
        0.25, 0.75,
        0.25, 0.5,
        0, 0.5,
        0, 0.75,
        0.25, 0.5,
        //Second Pass
        0.25, 0.75,
        0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.75,
        0.25, 0.75,
        0.25, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5,
        //Third Pass
        0.5, 0.75,
        0.75, 0.75,
        0.75, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.75,
        0.75, 0.5,
        //Fourth Pass
        1, 0.5,
        0.75, 0.75,
        1, 0.75,
        1, 0.5,
        0.75, 0.5,
        0.75, 0.75,
        //Sixth No
        0.75, 0.25,
        0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.25,
        0.75, 0.25,
        0.75, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5,
        //Fifth No 
        0.75, 0.75,
        0.5, 1,
        0.5, 0.75,
        0.75, 0.75,
        0.75, 1,
        0.5, 1
      ]
    );

    let UVCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, UVCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, UVCoord, gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc_UVCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc_UVCoord);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);


    let image = new Image();
    let url = "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49093406911_7d185dba0e_b.jpg";
    requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(image, url);
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function() 
    {
      loadTexture(gl, texture, image);
    }
}

function loadTexture(gl, texture, image)
{
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
}

....

function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) //https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html
{
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) 
  {
    img.crossOrigin = "";
  }
}

....
```

The First problem is that the texture is not loaded at the main function this is because the `loadTexure` function get started after the main function is finished so, is there anyway to load the texture at the first time of drawing the cube??

These are the pictures for above problem..

[image: Before changing the angle]

After changing the angle by pushing the arrow keys...

[image: After changing the angle]

The second problem is that the texture is not applied properly at the right side of cube and the bottom..

By changing the texture coordinates I can see the 1, 2, 3, 4 on the cube but no matter how I editted the order of coordinates I still cannot see 5, 6 on the right face of the cube and the bottom face of the cube ... here is the texture [image](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49093406911_7d185dba0e_b.jpg)

[image: The right face of the cube]
[image: The bottom face of the cube]

And the last question is that If I want to change the faces to be mapped, do I have to modify the texture coordinates arrays or indices array or vertices array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The First problem is that the texture is not loaded at the main function this is because the loadTexure function get started after the main function is finished so, is there anyway to load the texture at the first time of drawing the cube??

Textures are loaded asynchonously so you have about 3 choices

1. Wait for the texture to load before starting
2. Create a renderable texture, render continuously using a requestAnimationFrame loop, replace the texture contents it with the image when the image has loaded.

   since your render loop would have things rendering contiunously problem solved.
3. Create a renderable texture, replace the texture contents it with the image when the image has loaded and render again

It looks like you're currently doing #3 but you're not rendering again after the texture loads. Inside your `loadTexture` function call your render/draw function.

If you want to do #1 you need to create the `Image` and set its `onload` outside the rest of your code. Something like

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = initRestOfCode;
img.src = urlForImage;

function initRestOfCode() { ...
```

> The second problem is that the texture is not applied properly at the right side of cube and the bottom..

Just checking first you turned on depth test and face culling

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
```

But otherwise the texture coordinates don't match the vertex positions. There are 4 vertex positions per cube face but the code has 6 texture coordinates per cube face. They need to match, just 4 texture coordinates per face. Attributes in WebGL represent parallel arrays

[image]

Comment: First problem was simple... I feel myself dumb that I could not find out by myself.. The second one is that I had no idea that I needed only four texture coordinates to map the cube, I always thought that texture coordinates would need 6 points but that was my prejudice... Thank you so much sir! Have a great day sir!

Comment: In the normal case  attributes have to have the same number of values. They represent [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)